# Evaluating $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{K_0 \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{B(\phi)}} \right)}{B(\phi)} \, \sin^2 \phi \, \mathrm{d} \phi$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I am currently working on the evaluation of the following definite integral, which emerged during the application of an inverse Fourier transform:
$$
f(x) =  \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{K_0 \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{B(\phi)}} \right)}{B(\phi)} \, \sin^2 \phi \, \mathrm{d} \phi, \tag{1}
$$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $B = 1 + A \sin^2\phi \cos^2 \phi$ with $A \in [-4, \infty)$. In this expression, $K_0$ represents the modified Bessel function of the second kind with a zeroth-order.
It can readily be checked that $B(\phi) \ge 0, \forall \phi \in [0,\pi/2]$.

My initial approach was to employ a change of variables by substituting $u = x/\sqrt{B(\phi)}$. However, this method introduced a challenge, as it rendered the upper and lower limits of the integral equal. I am seeking assistance from this forum to explore the possibility of evaluating this integral analytically.

**EDIT:**

The above integral arose after applying the inverse Fourier transform of:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\infty \frac{k J_0(xk)}{1+B(\phi) k^2} \, \sin^2\phi \, \mathrm{d}k \, \mathrm{d}\phi \, , \tag{2}
$$
with $k$ denoting the wavenumber.
It can be verified that the integral over the range of 0 to $2\pi$ is exactly four times the integral over the range of 0 to $\pi/2$.

By evaluating the integral (2) with respect to $\phi$ first I get
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{2\pi \, k J_0(xk)}{\sqrt{(1+k^2) \left( 4+(A+4)k^2 \right)}} \, \mathrm{d} k \, . \tag{3}
$$

Comment: Can you share what is the original integral? (like prior to the application of the inverse Fourier transform).. maybe that is easier to evaluate by other methods.

Comment: @Zacky OK. I have provided an edit to the question to clarify the first integration with respect to $k$.

Comment: The resulting integral, after evaluating the integral (2) wrt $\phi$, strongly reminds me of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4710744/515527) result: $$\int_0^\infty x\operatorname{J}_0(rx)\frac{e^{-z\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx=\frac{e^{-a\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}$$

I'm thinking that it might be worth to evaluate:
$$\int_0^\infty x\operatorname{J}_0(rx)\frac{e^{-z\sqrt{x^2+b^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx$$
And then integrate both sides wrt $z$ (from $0$ to $\infty$) and get your integral..

Comment: @Zacky Thanks for the hint. I will give it a try now.