# Derive a closed-form expression for $\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{u \operatorname{J}_0(xu)}{\sqrt{1+u^2} \sqrt{1+\beta u^2}} \, \mathrm{d} u$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals, bessel-functions

My objective is to derive analytically a closed-form expression for the following integral:
$$
\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{u \operatorname{J}_0(xu)}{\sqrt{1+u^2} \sqrt{1+\beta u^2}} \, \mathrm{d} u, \tag{1}
$$

Here, $\operatorname{J}_0$ represents the zeroth-order Bessel function of the first kind, and both $x$ and $\beta$ are positive real numbers.

It is worth noting that obtaining a closed-form expression for integral (1) is straightforward when $\beta$ takes on the values of either $0$ or $1$.

This question is inspired from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4787800/evaluating-int-0-frac-pi2-frack-0-left-fracx-sqrtb-phi-ri) in which Mr Zacky suggested using [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4709944/integrating-int-0-infty-fracu2-sqrtu2a2j-1rue-z-sqrtu2a2d/4710744#4710744) to obtain a solution of the problem.
Any help with this is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It is a definite integral, not indefinite integral.

Comment: "Indefinite" or "definite"?

Comment: Perhaps less straight forward, but $\beta=-1$ results in $$\frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi} x^2} G_{0,4}^{3,0}\left(-\frac{1}{16} \left(i x^2\right),\frac{1}{2}|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ in terms of the [Meijer G-function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeijerG-Function.html).